# How to split string by uppercase letters or the dollar ('$') sign

Tags: vba

I have this string in a cell that reads "No penalty No c $400"

I'd like to split the string into: str1 = "No penalty"; str2 = "No penalty"; str3 = "$400"

I thought of splitting the string by uppercase letters and the $ sign but I'm not sure how.

```
    stri = "No penalty No penalty $400"
    temp = ""
    temp = stri
    For i = 1 To Len(temp)
        If Mid(temp, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(temp, i, 1)) Then
            If i <> 1 Then
                str1 = Left(temp, i - 1) + Right(temp, Len(temp) - i + 1)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    splitbycaps = temp
```

I'm pretty lost right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim s As String
    Dim ocMatches As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim a() As String

    s = "No penalty No penalty $400"
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "[A-Z$][^A-Z$]*"
        Set ocMatches = .Execute(s)
    End With
    If ocMatches.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim a(1 To ocMatches.Count)
        For i = 1 To UBound(a)
            a(i) = Trim(ocMatches(i - 1).Value)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have similar problem where the string is "No penalty 20% after deductible 40% after deductible" and should be split as "No penalty", "20% after deductible", and "40% after deductible". I tried replacing the "$" to "%" but it splits in the % part. How can i retain the numbers?

Comment: @RobinScherbatsky try `(?:(?! \d+%)[\s\S])*`